# PHP - Modify only one GET parameter

Tags: php, http, http-get

Let's say I have this URL - `http://www.example.com/index.php?id=123&version=3&course=234&version=4` and I only want to change one parameter without 'resetting' the formula using `href`. How do I go about it?

Let's say from the above URL I want to change `id` from 123 to 758. Using the full URL I'd do `<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?id=758&course=234&version=4">Change id</a>`

Now let's say I want to change `version` from 4 to 5 in the URL. What can I do to keep `id` either 123 or 758 without resetting `version` using `href` without losing the other parameters?

Comment: Please provide more details what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I am going to use a system of filtering using `href` tag through the URL for say `id`, `course` and `version`... If I change href  for version I don't want to lose the values for id and course. I know I can use $_GET in my `href`. I want to know whether there is an easy way round. Where I can change one parameter rather than using $_GET for a whole url as it will become too long codewise and can cause errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple work around for this is to add the value once more at the end. In GET calls to urls if there are same key with different value it will take always the latest

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=758&course=234&version=4&id=123

Best way to work with this is to use parse_url() function to get the query as key value pair array and use http_build_query() function to make it back to the http query form.

Comment: You can get the URL from the anchor via a regex e.g. `href=\"(.*?)\"` then `parse_url()` and `http_build_query()` as suggested are probably what you want to do. I'd say don't rely on quirks like passing the same parameter twice because you never know if all browsers will do the same thing.